# Prove that the set $A=\lbrace (x,y)\in R^2 : xy\leq 1 \rbrace$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis

I already know that a bounded and closed set $A$  in $R^k$ is compact. In another hand, how i can prove that the set
$$A=\lbrace (x,y)\in R^2 : xy\leq 1 \rbrace$$
is closed?. Obviously $ A $ is already bounded. I know that $ A ^ c $ is an open set, but, as the same way, how can I prove that $A^c$ is an open set in $R^2$?

Comment: That set is not bounded. What was your argument that it is bounded? If you put it here someone could say what step(s) are not right.

Comment: Also, if you know $A^c$ is open, then $A$ is closed by definition.

Comment: @ElliotG OP knows this. OP says they "know" the set's complement is open (how they know, I have no clue), but they don't know how to prove it. I'd argue that they just don't know.